# How to call two functions in javascript from onchange event

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

There is a textbox where I want to enter only numbers and on entering the 6th number I want to call a code behind method by clicking client side hidden button's onclick event (server side ) in which I want to do some operation.

The problem I am facing is that when run the below code sample when I enter any number in the  text box only the first method AllowNumericOnly() is called not the second method callMethod() is called even after the first method returns true value.

Why, I can't understand?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

function callMethod()
{
    alert('1');
    var PinCodeValue=document.getElementById('txtTest').value;
    var Pincodelength = PinCodeValue.length;
    if(Pincodelength>4)
    {
        alert('Pincodelength>4');
        document.getElementById('Button1').click(); 
        return true;                      
    }
    return false;
}       

function AllowNumericOnly(e, t) {
    try {
        if (window.event) {
            var charCode = window.event.keyCode;
        }
        else if (e) {
            var charCode = e.which;
        }
        else { return true; }
        if ((charCode > 47 && charCode < 58) || charCode == 8 || charCode == 0)
        {
        alert('true');
            return true;
            }
        else
        {
        alert('false');
            return false;
            }
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err.Description);
    }
}
</script>


<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" MaxLength="7" onkeypress="return       AllowNumericOnly(event,this); callMethod();" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Style="display: none"     OnClientClick="alert1();"
            OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: create a new function that calls both of the function, the onchange then calls the new function

Comment: Just use a single method, `callMethod()` and call `AllowNumericOnly` from within there. You wound only call all the code when enough valid characters are entered.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to create a little function that will call both of these as it improves the code separation.

```
function doBoth(e, t) {
   var result = AllowNumericOnly(e, t)
   callMethod()
   return result;
}
```

Then your ASP code would read

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" MaxLength="7" onkeypress="return doBoth(event, this);" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

Or an alternative approach would be to add multiple handlers in jQuery, again this could be done in a single function but this is just to illustrate. In your case it would make your return value a bit harder

```
$("#txtTest").keypress(function() { AllowNumericOnly(); })
$("#txtTest").keypress(function() { callMethod(); })
```

Comment: @user3567527: Great - please feel free to click the tick and accept this as the answer if it solved your problem (and possibly upvote the answer). Voting is what drives the community :)

Answer (score 0):

onkeypress="if(AllowNumericOnly(event,this))return callMethod(); else return false;"

Answer (score 0):

You could use jquery and bind two event handlers to one element (button)...

```
$( "#Button1" ).bind( "click", function() {
    alert( "User clicked on 'foo.'" );
});

$( "#Button1" ).bind( "click", function() {
    alert( "User really clicked on 'foo.'" );
});
```

In the above case both handlers work, jQuery allows multiples in this manner... just be aware the fire in the order they are bound. See [this link for more info](http://api.jquery.com/bind/#entry-longdesc)